# How can I reduce noise from my neighbor's pool pump 12’ to 15’ away from my house?

Tags: pump, pool, noise

I need fencing type/material to use to block low hum of pool pump located 12’ to 15’ from family room hurricane impact windows. I'm planning to erecta  6’ high fence on property line between houses spanning about 18’. The pump is used on high and low speed creating noise.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered user accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: A fence isn't going to block low-frequency noise. You need to work with your neighbor (rather than insulting them) to isolate the pump from the ground.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a fence at least as high as the wavelength, with substantial mass, and for a 60 Hz hum, for example, that's a 5 meter (15 ft) high fence, made of concrete, such as used for [highway sound barriers](https://smithmidland.com/sound-wall).

Comment: Probably cheaper to offer to pay for a soundproof enclosure for his pump.

Comment: Yea 15 feet would be to high. Since there are schrubs around pump/motor platform I would need a box like enclosure over pump alone but overhead piping makes it difficult to design and create. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JRaef A soundproof enclosure isn't going to fix low frequency resonance, it will go right through that enclosure like a house of cards. Vibration isolation and dampening is the only answer.

Comment: As @JRaef states, vibrations will go through the ground. Commercial pumps are usually set on spring/rubber vibration absorbers, as well as enclosed.